Не работает флаг Pn в Zenmap
Тестирую сеть через ВПН при помощи nmap на windows. ICMP отключен, поэтому и использую флаг PN, но хост все равно не сканируется. На картинках ниже видно, что хост не считается поднятым, при этом TNC выдает true на 80 порт. Перепробовал уже несколько версий nmap, везде одно и тоже.




Так и не получилось исправить, использовал rustscan, вдруг кому поможет.
